# Postgres Copy - Escape character import from CSV to table

Tags: shell, csv, import, psql

i have file.csv with this format:

```
2|field1|field2|field3
2|field1|field2|field3
```

I would use in Postgres copy command for import data from file to table. Field1,field2,filed3 are table columns.

How can I exclude the first value before first | ?

Thanks

copy data escape first field

Comment: You cannot do that. What you could do is add an extra column to the table and drop that column when you are done.